# bash find using regex is not case sensitive

Tags: regex, bash, unix, find

I need to find files starting with three lowercase letters but for some reason I'm getting an undesired case-insensitive behavior.
I'm using find with the -regex option but it finds even the files starting with capital.

```
$ find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[a-z]{3}\w+\.abc'
./TTTxxx.abc
./tttyyy.abc
```

prints the same as:

```
$ find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[A-Z]{3}\w+\.abc'
./TTTxxx.abc
./tttyyy.abc
```

If instead of using a range of characters I use a single character, works as sensitive, printing only the lowercase file.

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[t]{3}\w+\.abc'
./tttyyy.abc
```

I've tried using different regextypes and the result is the same.

In addition, an egrep to seems to work:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/.+\.abc' |  egrep '/[a-z]\w+\.abc'
./tttyyy.abc
```

Why is the "find -regex" case-insensitive when using a char range ?

**Note:** I need to use find as I need the -exec option.

Many thanks.

Comment: Nice question, I didn't know about this behaviour. Here's a [cross site duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash), with an extensive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accroding to [Why does [A-Z] match lowercase letters in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash), the collation is the issue here:

> Standard collations with locales such as en_US have the following order:
>
> `aAbBcC...xXyYzZ`
>
> Between `a` and `z` (in `[a-z]`) are ALL uppercase letters, except for `Z`.
>   Between `A` and `Z` (in `[A-Z]`) are ALL lowercase letters, except for `a`.

So you need to list explicitly all lowercase letters or change the collation:
`$ export LC_COLLATE=C` and use standard `[a-z]`.

`[...]{3}\w\.abc` - this pattern, where `[...]` is `[a-z]` or lowercase letters listed, will get you filenames.

Comment: or, as mentioned in the end of the answer, you can use POSIX character class `[[:lower:]]`

Comment: Thanks Michal for solving the enigma ! Thanks @Aserre for the tip! It works now.